# Can I get Android to not expand the top notification?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notifications, htc-one

I've had Android 4.4 (on a HTC One) for a while now. And it never automatically expanded notifications. A short while ago I accidentally expanded one of the notifications, and at that point the system started to always expand the top notification.

From what I understand from various sites on the *net, expanding the top notification is now the default behavior. But I'd like to have the old behavior back. Is there a setting for this, and if so where (preferably without installing some app)?

Googling for me only turns up articles about apps that expand all notifications automatically (it's the opposite I want) and about disabling individual notifications (don't want that either) or programmatically disabling the notifications area altogether (either).

Comment: I don't have an HTC to try this on, but what happens when you 2-finger swipe down from the top? Some manufactures mess about with the menu from that gesture. How about a long press on any of the areas revealed with the notifications bar expanded? Yeah, grabbing at straws, but you did your homework before posting!

Comment: 2-finger swipe opens the settings just as it's supposed to do, but I don't find anything in there that looks like it would help here. Tried long press already: when on a notification gives me a popup saying "App-Info". Nothing when done on any other area.